How to create overlapping diamonds
My task is to create n diamonds with height 2n-1 and b as blocks, that are overlapping in the middle like this. The overlapping point means that diamonds share blocks at the middle level.

My current output looks like this:

This is my code:
def draw_diamonds(n, b):
    height = 2 * n - 1
    diamonds = []

    for i in range(height):
        line = ""
        for j in range(n):
            if i < n:
                if j == 0:
                    line += " " * (n - i - 1) + b * (2 * i + 1)
                else:
                    line += " " * (n - i) + b * (2 * i + 1) + ""
            else:
                if j == 0:
                    line += " " * (i - n + 1) + b * (2 * (height - i) - 1)
                else:
                    line += " " * (i - n + 1) + b * (2 * (height - i) - 1) + " "
        diamonds.append(line)

    for line in diamonds:
        print(line)

n, b = map(str, input().split())
draw_diamonds(int(n), b)


How do u write value draw_diamonds(int(n), b)?

@user19077881 They don't need to... b is the character to use for the pattern.

They don't look overlapping / sharing to me...

They're touching but not overlapping. The right-most * of the first diamond is not the left-most * of the second.

I recommend to re-work your logic and simplify it. Only think of how you can print a single diamond, scaling it afterwards is easy (done in the code below via  * diamonds_count).
Check the following code which generates your expected pattern:
def draw_diamonds(diamonds_count, symbol):
    height = 2 * diamonds_count - 1

    diamonds = [height * diamonds_count * symbol]
    space_count = 0
    symbol_count = height

    while(symbol_count != 1):
        symbol_count -= 2
        space_count += 1

        line = (space_count * " " + symbol_count * symbol + space_count * " ") * diamonds_count

        diamonds.insert(0, line)
        diamonds.insert(len(diamonds), line)

    for line in diamonds:
        print(line)

n, b = map(str, input().split())
draw_diamonds(int(n), b)

User input of 3 and * leads to that result:
  *    *    *  
 ***  ***  *** 
***************
 ***  ***  *** 
  *    *    *  

